# Possible to connect to VNC server only with a NTLM Hash?

Tags: remote-desktop, ntlm

I'm using a training lab to learn computing security. And I retrieved the hash of the admin in this form:

```
admin:1001:NO PASSWORD*********************:D4BF5A8658AFXXXXXXXX5B8DBB60859746:::
```

So, I just have the NTLM part (not the LM), and cracking password is very hard without LM part.

So I would like to know if there is a tool to connect to the VNC service (port 5900) of the remote computer only using the NTLM hash.

Comment: You can't pass the hash with VNC. If the Windows "admin" user is using the same password for the VNC service, you'll have to crack the hash and use that.

Comment: NTLM cracking is not that hard, let it run for a few days....

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use psexec module from Metasploit.. however, for this to work port 445 should be open on the target. psexec module will require the username and password hash to deploy a meterpreter backdoor. once, achieved you can run the vnc post exploitation module and will be presented with a nice GUI of the target, All the best.

Answer (score -2):

you need VNC password hash from captured traffic (challenge and response). and hashcat